# Mongoose aggregating count with different criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have users and and users have documents. Users can have maximum 100 documents. Users can only edit maximum 50 documents. When I am inserting a new document, first I query User.documents to find number of documents and then I query Documents with `userId` and `isFinished=true` and check if there is a room for editable document. Is there a way to get both `total` and `finished` documents of the user with a single query? My current code is something like below.

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, index: {unique: true, sparse: true}},
    password: String,
    });

    UserSchema.virtual('documents',{
    ref: 'Document',
    localField:'_id',
    foreignField:'owner'
});


var DocumentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    owner : { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    name: String,
    data: String,
    isFinished: {
        type: Boolean, default: false
    },
    updateDate: Date
    });


 User.findOne({_id: req.userId}).populate('documents').exec(function(err, user) {

 // user.documents == total user documents

if (user.documents && user.documents.length < 100) {

  Document.count({owner:req.userId,isFinished:true},function(err,count) {
  // count == finished user documents
        if (count < 50) {

            // do something
        }


        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem with aggregation.

```
Document.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            owner:user._id
        }},
    { $group: {
        "_id": "$owner",
        "totalCount": {
            $sum: 1
        },
        "finishedCount" : { $sum:  { $cond: ["$isFinished",1,0]} }
    }
    }]).exec(function (err,result) {
    if ( result && result.length > 0) {
        if ( result[0].totalCount >= config.registeredTotalLimit) {
            // Registered total limit is reached
            console.log('Register registeredTotalLimit');
        }
        if (result[0].finishedCount >= config.registeredActiveLimit) {
            // Registered active limit is reached
            console.log('Register registeredActiveLimit');
        }
    }
```